# Mysql Query to get segregated results is not working

Tags: mysql

I have few records in a table `sample` like this:

```
 -------------------------------------  
  name           | category_type    
  -------------------------------------  
  item 1         | a                   
  item 2         | b                  
  item 3         | a   
  item 4         | a   
  item 5         | b
```

I am trying to make a query which will give result by category type
for eg :

```
a -> item1 , item 3 , item 4   
  b -> item2, item 5
```

I have tried group by clause but its not working

Answer (score 1):

```
select
   category_type,
   group_concat(name) as names
from 
   sample
group by
   category_type
```

Answer (score 1):

GROUP_CONCAT is what you are looking for

```
SELECT category_type, GROUP_CONCAT(name SEPARATOR ', ')
FROM sample
GROUP BY category_type
```

See the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) for details

Note that I am using SEPARATOR to allow you to have a comma separated list instead of just the plain list. You can use what you want as separator